# How to deal with many objects in a Spring Boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-applications

I'm currently working on a project which consists of an angular frontend and a Spring Boot Backend. For the communication, I want to use a normal RestController. Somewhat like this:

```
@RestController
public class BuildingController {
   @PostMapping("/building")
   void addBuilding(@RequestBody Building building){...}
```

In the frontend the user defines a building which contains zones, rooms, walls, roofs ... . This data is sent to the backend where the created objects will be stored in the database and some calculations are done. The calculation results will then be sent back to the frontend.

To this, it's necessary that not only the building object is sent to the backend but also the objects of the walls, etc.

So my question would be if it is better to create a controller for every class(Building, wall, room, etc.), have just one Controller which excepts every Object at once, or maybe an even better way than my proposed solutions?

```
@RestController
public class allMightyController{
   @PostMapping("/building")
   void addAll(@RequestBody Building building, List<Room>, List<Wall>, ...){...}
```

Comment: It depends on your application business needs and which calculations exactly are done. Room and wall can't exist without building, so it could be one endpoint that accepts Building as a complex object that has list of walls. rooms, etc. inside. However you could have also separate endpoints or controllers for each operation you need if you want to be able to do something only with room object that comes from  frontend.

Comment: The calculations are always for a howl building and not for a room only so it wouldn't make sense to send an object of a room individual.

Comment: Then is should be "void addBuilding(@RequestBody Building building)" with List<Room>, List<Wall>, etc, as fields of Building class

Comment: Ok, I will do it like this. Thanks for the help!